# SysVinit service wrapper for systemd on arch linux

Tags: arch-linux, systemd, services, sysvinit

I'm using Arch Linux and I'd like to use Cisco AnyConnect out of the box. Cisco AnyConnect is delivered as SysVinit service. The installation fails because directories like /etc/rc.d are missing. I added the missing directories but then the installation fails because there is no command `service` to manage services. I checked e.g. CentOS with systemd. There is the script `/usr/sbin/service` that is a wrapper that calls systemd.

Does something like this exist for Arch Linux? I only found the package [systemd-sysvcompat](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/?name=systemd-sysvcompat) but it's already installed and doesn't provide the necessary directory structure and the missing commands. I don't want to switch from systemd to sysvinit. I'm looking for a package to use SysVinit services with systemd on Arch Linux like it's possible on CentOS or Ubuntu.

In a forum for Cisco I found the statement that Cisco AnyConnect is only supported for Ubuntu, Red Hat and some other distributions. Arch Linux is not supported and timely support for systemd is unlikely.

I get Cisco AnyConnect from my university in a specific version. My university also only supports Ubuntu and Red Hat. I'd like to use it to connect to the VPN of my university.

Probably there are other ways to achieve this but I'm interested if I can fix it with a call to `pacman -S`.

Answer (score 0):

Your expectations from [systemd-sysvcompat](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/?name=systemd-sysvcompat) are wrong. Do read [Arch Linux wiki related section](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd#systemd-sysvcompat). I also think you are wrong in looking for a package to use SysVinit services. I think you should look the other way around: for a package that adopt Cisco AnyConnect, or a FOSS replacement, to systemd.

1. Are you aware of [Arch Linux wiki OpenConnect article](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/OpenConnect)? I am not familiar with [OpenConnect](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/?name=openconnect). Since no answers were given until now, I think mentioning it is in place, despite my unfamiliarity.
2. While I am at it, I think [Systemd#Writing_unit_files](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd#Writing_unit_files) also worth mentioning. Depending on the Cisco AnyConnect SysVInit service complexity, it might not be hard to try and write a systemd unit to support systemd. In fact, you mentioned 
   Ubuntu and Red Hat. Don't both Ubuntu and Red Hat systemd based for several years now? Can't one adopt their systemd related unit to Arch Linux with little work?
3. [An AUR related AnyConnect client](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/anyconnect-client/) has its own vpnagentd.service systemd unit.
4. Have you tried searching, or asking, at [Arch Linux forums](https://bbs.archlinux.org/)?

I agree my answer leaves the poster with a whole bunch of loose ends. Or even much more than loose ends. Once again, this question was left not answered at all for more then half a year. Hopefully, some pieces of information at the right direction are better than none.

---